# Display Problems with Visual Studio Code (1.83.1) on Ubuntu (20.04.6 LTS)

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I've been using Microsoft VS Code with Ubuntu (20.04.6 LTS) for a while now. When I launch the app now, the window display is corrupted (see screenshots) such that I cannot use the software. So far, I've tried installing all updates for Ubuntu and re-installing VS Code. This issue still persists after trying these two things.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

[Visual Studio Code doesn't display correctly (example 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMMZP.jpg)

[Visual Studio Code doesn't display correctly (example 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DbyD.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Disabling hardware acceleration fixed this issue for me.

```
code --disable-gpu
```

To configure this permanently:
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_disable-gpu-acceleration